# How to get next available number between given numbers for each of the table row based on condition of that row

Tags: sql, oracle

For each of the Product record that I get from the Oracle DB table, I need to generate next available number between the given number range. While generating the next number, there is no conditinal check involved as long as there are unused numbers available in the given number range. When it already reached the last number in the given number range, it should repeat from the beginning but from this time onwards it should  generate it based on conditional check.

I'll try to put my requirement in a simple way.

Sequence Number range to be used: 1-3 (1 till 3)

Data in PRODUCT table:

```
Name  Start Date    End Date
P1    1-Nov
P2    1-Nov         5-Nov
P3    1-Nov
P4    2-Nov
p2    2-Nov
```

Lets say product without End date are active product, product with end date are inactive one.

Expected Output:

```
Name  Start Date    End Date    SequenceNumber     Comment
P1    1-Nov                     1                  No conditional check
P2    1-Nov         5-Nov       2                  No conditional check
P3    1-Nov                     3                  No conditional check
P4    2-Nov                     2                  Sequence should start from 1 again but with condition check while generating sequence. Condition: If the generated number is used in any other active product, move on to next number  
p2    2-Nov                                        In this case, all 1, 2, 3 are mapped to active products. so no sequence is generated.
```

Question:
How do get the desired output using select statement? It would be helpful, it you can suggest some approach on this. Thanks.

Comment: 1.) Additional explanation on the 4th row mentioned under 'Expected Output': Since we already completed using all the sequence number from the given range, it tries to start from 1. However, we have the sequence number '1' already being used by the active product 'P1'.  Hence it uses the next sequence number '2' for the product 'P4'. 

2.) Given Number range need not be dynamic. In my real scenario, number from 1 till 6 should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like interrow - intercolumn processing which means tha you could use [Oracle's MODEL Clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm). It works much like excel sheet addressing individual cells.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        (   Select 'P1' "A_NAME",  Date '2023-11-01' "START_DATE", Null "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P2' "A_NAME",  Date '2023-11-01' "START_DATE", Date '2023-11-05' "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P3' "A_NAME",  Date '2023-11-01' "START_DATE", Null "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P4' "A_NAME",  Date '2023-11-02' "START_DATE", Null "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'P2' "A_NAME",  Date '2023-11-02' "START_DATE", Null "END_DATE" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    A_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQUENCE_NUMBER
FROM    ( Select  ROWNUM "RN", A_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, 0 "SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
          From    tbl
        )
             -- RowNum (RN) used to uniquely identify rows
        MODEL   Dimension By ( RN )
                Measures ( A_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 0 "SEQUENCES" )
        RULES
            ( SEQUENCE_NUMBER[ANY] =  Case When   Case  When Nvl(Count(START_DATE)[RN < CV()], 0) + 1 <= 3 
                                                        Then Nvl(Count(START_DATE)[RN < CV()], 0) + 1 
                                                  Else 0 End = 0
                                              Then  0
                                      Else   Case When Nvl(Count(START_DATE)[RN < CV()], 0) + 1 <= 3 
                                                  Then Nvl(Count(START_DATE)[RN < CV()], 0) + 1   -- this gives non conditional sequences (1 - 3)
                                             Else 0 End
                                      End,
                  --
               -- added column SEQUENCES to control the sequence numbers used before the current row
                  SEQUENCES[ANY] = Nvl(Max(SEQUENCE_NUMBER)[RN < CV(RN)], 0),
                  --
                  SEQUENCE_NUMBER[ANY] = Case When SEQUENCE_NUMBER[CV()] = 0
                                              Then Case When SEQUENCES[CV()] = 3 And 
                                                             Min(SEQUENCE_NUMBER)[RN < CV()] = 1 And
                                                             Max(SEQUENCES)[RN < CV()] < 3
                                                        Then Min(SEQUENCE_NUMBER)[RN < CV()] + 1  -- this gives conditional sequence when first is used (used + 1)
                                                   End  -- no Else part (same as Else Null) gives Null when (used + 1) is also done
                                         Else SEQUENCE_NUMBER[CV()]
                                         End
                )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_NAME START_DATE END_DATE  SEQUENCE_NUMBER                            
------ ---------- --------- --------------- 
P1     01-NOV-23                          1 
P2     01-NOV-23  05-NOV-23               2 
P3     01-NOV-23                          3 
P4     02-NOV-23                          2 
P2     02-NOV-23                             */
```